# How can I run pre commit hooks again after running "git commit --no-verify"?

Tags: git, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit

Let's say I committed some code to the remote repository but skipped the commit hooks with `git commit --no-verify` since it was a WIP branch. But now I want to run those pre commit hooks on the same commit using `git commit --amend`. How can I run the previously skipped commit hooks on a commit?

Thanks

Comment: `git reset --soft HEAD~1`, then re-commit?

Comment: Oh I see, that would work. Is there another way without the git reset? I basically am trying to run the pre commit hook manually only on files inside the commit.

Comment: Seems like the best way is to do a git reset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make only one commit on the WIP branch, `git commit --amend --no-edit` can invoke the hooks.

For a more general case in which you may have one or more than one commit, you can use `git rebase` and `git commit --amend` to invoke the hooks on each of them. Suppose the branch history is `O-A-B-C-D(HEAD->WIP)` and you want to run the hooks on `ABCD`.

```
git switch $WIP
git rebase -f O --exec 'git commit --amend --no-edit'
```

The commits `ABCD` will be reapplied one by one, and after each apply `git commit --amend --no-edit` is called and invokes the hooks.

Answer (score 1):

I did not install pre-commit before commiting. So lint was failing in pull request. To fix that, I installed pre-commit using,

```
pip install pre-commit
pre-commit install
```

This will set up pre-commit hooks for your Git repository.
Now, do this,

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
git commit -m "Same commit message"
```

And pre-commits ran again. Yeyy.
Then push your branch using `-f`

```
git push -f origin branch_name
```

Reference: Brian's comment.